# Start axis label from specific point

Tags: ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
ggplot(mushroom,aes(x=date,y=value)) +
 geom_point(aes(fill=type),shape=21,size=3)+
 geom_line(aes(color=type))+
 theme_bw()+
 theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

This is giving me something like this: [image]

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Note, the x-axis labels. I want mine also to start from Nov 01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = c('start_date', 'end_date'))
```

I don't know in what format you have date column: 
start_date would be Nov 01 and end_date Nov 22